# npm audit replace nsp check returns with E400 bad request

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I'm running an audit inside CI on gitlab but I'm getting this error on `npm audit` .

`$ npm audit
    npm ERR! code E400
    npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - POST https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits`

a version of the node is 8.11.1
i run `npm i --package-lock-only`

then I run `npm i -g npm@6` which installs version 6.5.0

this is all inside of a container in the on the CI run.

Comment: Your `package-lock` might be corrupt. Have you tried deleting it then running `npm i` to refresh it?

Comment: It's a bug: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20604#issuecomment-393218941